# iOS caching PAC file

Tags: ios, ipad, proxy

I have a large number of iPads (minis + airs) running the latest iOS for the device. (9.3.5 on the minis).

They are all configured by MDM to use a wifi network with a PAC file. After having some issues with SSL interception on a domain I've made a change to the PAC file to fix it but my iOS devices aren't picking up on it. Using our web filter reporting I can't see the iPads make any requests for the PAC file which means they must be using an old cached version of it.

I've tried multiple hard reboots on the devices and clearing the safari cache to no avail.

Anyone know how to make iOS re-download the pac file?